# Placing e.currentTarget.value into Typescript variable with constant type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, constants

If my interface defines MyObject.type to be of type (constant): 'orange' | 'apple',

I get an error when I do: MyObject.type = e.currentTarget.value in the onChange method because it could be any string, even though I know that it will always give the right answer due to it being a select dropdown.

Is there a better, cleaner way to avoid the Typescript error this generates without using //@ts-ignore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will have to use a type assertion. For example:

```js
MyObject.type = e.currentTarget.value as 'orange' | 'apple';
```